# Extract Individual Line Segment Coordinates from Boundary Image - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a MATLAB script that gives me the boundary lines of an image using `bwboundaries()`.
Now, after plotting that image, I am getting the complete image, formed from various straight line segments.
I would like to get the coordinates or show the individual line segments that form the boundary.

I think the method is called **digital straightness of lines**, but I want to know how to apply it here in this case.

```
[B,L,N] = bwboundaries(z,'noholes');
  for k=1:length(B),
     boundary = B{k};
     if(k > N)
       figure, plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
     else
       figure, plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',2);
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `regionprops('desired feature')` on the labelled image.

To generate a labelled image use

`bwlabel(Img)` (high memory usage)

or

`bw=bwconncomp(Img,conn)` (low memory use)

followed by

`labelmatrix(bw)`

The best way to proceed would probably be to use a `Hough Transform` to first get an idea of the lines present in the image. You can play around with `Hough Transform` to extract the end points of the lines.

Comment: I already have a boundary image. `regionprops()` wouldn't help here since I need to segment the boundary image into its constituent line segments.

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly I apologize for my bad answer. As your boundaries were straight line segments, I assummed `regionprops('ConvexHull')` would give you the required coordinates. I tried it out and found that only  approximate boundary coordinates are given.

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly I have edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding of your question,my idea is to use bwtraceboundary().

```
BW = imread('image.png');
imshow(BW,[]);
r = 165;   % you can get the r and c for your image using "impixelinfo"
c = 43;
contour = bwtraceboundary(BW,[r c],'W',4,Inf,'counterclockwise');
hold on;
plot(contour(:,2),contour(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
x=contour(:,2)'
y=contour(:,2)'
```

Am I answering your question?